# Compile 64 bit dll from a 32 bit VC++ dll - Sourcecode available for 32-bit dll

Tags: visual-c++

I have a 32-bit dll (developed in Win CE 5.0 and Microsoft eMbedded Visual C++ 4.0) from a third party.
They dont have 64 bit version. I would like to load this dll into 64 bit Vb.Net 2022.
Fortunately, I have the source code for the 32-bit dll. I need to recompile the source code to 64-bit dll.

I tried,

1. Add the new project in VS2022 -> Visual C++ -> Dynamic Link Library and add all the project files.
   Basically I'm a Vb.Net developer. It is complicate for me to configure the project properties.
   ex. Linker, Additional library directories etc.

I got few errors:
a. LNK1181  cannot open input file '.obj'
b. Error    LNK2001 unresolved external symbol MmMapIoSpace

2. I tried to load the 32-bit project in other VS version like 2008, 2010 and 2019.

- I cant able to open. Because of .sln file is not exist.

Which Software should I used to open the 32-bit dll project and recompile to 64-bit dll?

Since this is my very first question here and also first time in VC++. Guide me to solve this issue.